# GeoFlutterFire Flutter plugin for Firestore not return distance field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I'm using [GeoFlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire), a plugin for Flutter which sifts a collection for records that are near a specified GeoFirePoint.
A distance key is supposed to be returned with the Firestore `<DocumentSnapshot>s` but none is, only the default keys. When I seek it as below it returns null. The key doesn't exist.

1. I've tried changing the emulators GPS location, and then the
   usersAddressGeoFirePoint, no luck.
2. The instructions aren't clear on whether GeoFire creates this field, or needs it to pre-exist as a Firestore field. I've tried creating the Firestore field manually with a dummy value and then the value I get from the download is not the distance between the 2 `geopoint` points but the dummy value it was set on Firestore.

This is great frustration, I need the distance so I can show it on Cards in the app, my code is very close to the example code for the plugin, so I can't see why it doesn't work.

```
GeoFirePoint usersAddressGeoFirePoint = 
        geo.point(latitude: 56.088944, longitude: -4.151800);
    
localJobsStream = geo.collection(collectionRef: myFirestore.collection('JobsMeta'))
            .within(center: usersAddressGeoFirePoint, radius: 1000, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
    
localJobsStream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
    ${documentList[0].data.keys.contains('distance')}");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I checked the Geoflutterfire's **within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: strictMode)** method and it is returning  `Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>` as expected but for distance calculation, it is using a wrapper class **DistanceDocSnapshot** which has a DocumentSnapshot and distance variable.

When I debugged the **"within"** method, I found that DistanceDocSnapshot has a variable **distance** of type double but they are not setting the distance value in **DocumentSnapshot** before returning.

So the package has the data but of no use until we get it. By the time they fix this issue or we get to know any other way to use it, you can use below code to get the distance as they are using the same in the package and mentioned in readme [here GeoFlutterFire Package](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) :

```
 GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
     latitude: currentUserPos.latitude,
     longitude: currentUserPos.longitude,
 );

 double distance = center.distance(lat: geoPoint.latitude, lng: geoPoint.longitude);
```

**Update on the same**:
As per change log on package page we would not be able to access data using doc.data['distance'] anymore with **version 2.1.0**

Comment: hey, how would I pass the distance variable to the function

Comment: Where do you want to pass the distance variable? it returns the distance of type double when you call distance method on a GeoFirePoint passing the longitude and latitude in it.

Answer (score 1):

Returning distance with [geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire)

**Get user location**

```
Geolocator userLocation = Geolocator()
```

**Convert user location to GeoPoint**

```
GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude);
```

**From your DocumentSnapshot List data;**

*Convert the List data to lat long*

```
var latitude = data[index].data()['position']['geopoint'].latitude;

var longitude = data[index].data()['position']['geopoint'].longitude
```

Use the lat long to get distance with

> point.distance(latitude, longitude)

```
var distance = point.distance(lat: latitude, lng: longitude);
```